# Why app not launching on booting android device?

Tags: android, boot

I am testing the following app on HTC with Android 2.3.5. For some reason app is not launching on restarting or booting the phone.

I need to know where am I wrong exactly?

**BootReciever.java**

```
     import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {


     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "App started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     /*    
         Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
         startActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(startActivityIntent);
*/

        // context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
      import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}




}
```

**Android Manifest File:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbootreciever"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


   <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
android:name="com.example.hello_android_world.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


</intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.example.androidbootreciever.BootupReceiver">
            <intent-filter>                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The code is working on restart but not on turning on the phone after shutting it down. Here are the messages that I receive in my logcat:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You extended BootupReceiver with Activity?
It should be extended with Broadcast Receiver.

```
public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write following permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

If your application is stored on External storage then you should provide following intent filter,

```
<receiver android:name=".BootupReceiver">
      <intent-filter>                
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />                
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

See [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).

Comment: No error logs. Why am I not getting the toast message: "App started"?

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman did you change your `BootupReceiver` class to extends `BroadcastReceiver` ?

Comment: Still not working. I have edited my source code. Please check all files posted under my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Receiver:**

```
public class AutoStartBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent receivedIntent) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**Your Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.AutoStartBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Good luck!

Comment: You say, you don,t see Toast. Change "context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class));" from my example to "Toast.makeText(context, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" After boot you should see Toast.

Comment: Still not working. I have edited my source code. Please check all files posted under my question.

Comment: I think onRecieve() is not being detected on my device. I am going to post logcat messages here in a while.

Comment: Your code should works. Can not understand, why it does not. Try to launch app on another device or emulator. May be your HTC has some problems.

Comment: The code is working on RESTART but not on TURNING ON the phone after shutting it down. What could be the reason?